# Using CLAHE algorithm

Tags: c++, image-processing, itk

I am trying to use the source code provided [here](http://code.google.com/p/itk-clahe/source/browse/trunk/ClaheImageFilter.h?spec=svn8&r=8) for CLAHE algorithm.
When I include the "ClaheImageFilter.h" in my code and compile it, it gives me the following errors:

```
> In file included from /myDir/myCode.cxx:25:              
> /myDir/ClaheImageFilter.h: In member function ‘void
ClaheImageFilter<T_ItkImage>::_execute(typename T_ItkImage::Pointer)’:
> /myDir/ClaheImageFilter.h:1270: error: expected initializer
before ‘&’ token
> /myDir/ClaheImageFilter.h:1271: error:
‘roLargestSize’ was not declared in this scope
> /myDir/ClaheImageFilter.h: In member function ‘void
ClaheImageFilter<T_ItkImage>::_fromFlatArrayToItk(typename
T_ItkImage::PixelType*, const typename T_ItkImage::SizeType&, unsigned
int)’: 
> /myDir/ClaheImageFilter.h:1498: error: expected ‘;’
before ‘start’ /myDir/ClaheImageFilter.h:1499: error: ‘start’
was not declared in this scope
```

Does anyone know what is causing the problem?

- line 25 in `myCode.cxx` is just `#include "ClaheImageFilter.h"`.

Comment: Did you include the other dependencies that `ClaheImageFilter.h` needs?  At the beginning, they require these header files: `#include "itkImage.h"
#include "itkImportImageFilter.h"`.

Comment: Yes, I have those files in my itk library. Even when I include those files in "myCod.cxx" it does not complain about them at all.

Comment: were you able to compile the example in the code  with the provided cmakelists.txt or you have the same errors?